# How to use pdflib TET in Perl command-line tool in ubuntu

Tags: perl, pdf, pdflib

i just downloaded pdflib TET for ubuntu and can't figure out how to use the command line tool.  but when I go to command line tet command is not found. 
Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Selva Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three possibilities:

- go to the bin directory of your unpacked TET package and use in the command line "./tet"
- add the "bin" directory of your TET package to the PATH
- copy the "tet"-executable from the "bin" directory of your TET package to a directory which is included in the PATH

I don't think your question is TET related, it's more how to run a executable.